# Is it possible to test a webservice using just an endpoint and XML code using SOAPUI Pro tool?

Tags: soapui

I have been given an endpoint and piece of XML to test using SOAPUI Pro tool. Can someone please tell me how do i go about it with the available information?
Or should i be asking for more information from the developer?

Since i'm new to webservice testing, can someone please help me out?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use this information to test your web service. Try putting a ?wsdl at the end of your endpoint this should give you the wsdl. Load the wsdl url onto soapUI which will create the soapUI project. Once you have the project you can pretty much do anything on soapUI.

As you are a beginner i would suggest going through the tutorial soapUI offers.

http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/getting-started.html

Also, what is the xml that the developer gave you?