# How to check webservice(endpoint) is available from a particular server(not local)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, node.js, powershell

I wanted to check whether a webservice(endpoint)(.svc) is available from a particular web server.

For ex: The webserver **www.test123.com** is able to access the endpoint **

*htp://www.abc.com/ecl/CustomHistory.svc*

Comment: Tho I don't know if this is the correct way of doing this, we usually implement a ping function on our endpoints that returns a small code to check the health of the service. It's usually kept really lightweight so that it can be actively used to check, if one needs to. But usually the endpoint one is trying to reach will give back an appropriate answer (expected result, error, etc.), if no answer is coming and/or your connection is reset, you know your endpoint is not available.

Comment: As you tagged multiple languages, please specify which one you're asking about. If it's PowerShell, you could use `Invoke-WebRequest`

Answer (score 0):

If not PS as robdy states, see this answer...

> [Is it possible to test a webservice using just an endpoint and XML code using SOAPUI Pro tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411558/is-it-possible-to-test-a-webservice-using-just-an-endpoint-and-xml-code-using-so)

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is a physical or virtual machine where you can login in remotely.

Log-in to the server and browse the svc url from that machine web browser.